# Pandas: Merge data frames on datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, merge, datetimeindex

I have the following two dataframes that I have set date to DatetimeIndex `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['date']), inplace=True)` and would like to merge or join on date:

```
df.head(5)
        catcode_amt type    feccandid_amt   amount
date                
1915-12-31  A5000   24K     H6TX08100   1000
1916-12-31  T6100   24K     H8CA52052   500
1954-12-31  H3100   24K     S8AK00090   1000
1985-12-31  J7120   24E     H8OH18088   36
1997-12-31  z9600   24K     S6ND00058   2000
    
    
d.head(5)
         catcode_disp disposition   feccandid_disp  bills
date                
2007-12-31  A0000   support     S4HI00011               1
2007-12-31  A1000   oppose      S4IA00020', 'P20000741  1
2007-12-31  A1000   support     S8MT00010               1
2007-12-31  A1500   support     S6WI00061               2
2007-12-31  A1600   support     S4IA00020', 'P20000741  3
```

I have tried the following two methods but both return a MemoryError:

```
df.join(d, how='right')
```

I use the code below on dataframes that don't have date set to index.

```
merge=pd.merge(df,d, how='inner', on='date')
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can add parameters `left_index=True` and `right_index=True` if you need merge by indexes in function [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
merge=pd.merge(df,d, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Sample (first value of index in `d` was changed for matching):

```
print df
           catcode_amt type feccandid_amt  amount
date                                             
1915-12-31       A5000  24K     H6TX08100    1000
1916-12-31       T6100  24K     H8CA52052     500
1954-12-31       H3100  24K     S8AK00090    1000
1985-12-31       J7120  24E     H8OH18088      36
1997-12-31       z9600  24K     S6ND00058    2000

print d
           catcode_disp disposition            feccandid_disp  bills
date                                                                
1997-12-31        A0000     support                 S4HI00011    1.0
2007-12-31        A1000      oppose  S4IA00020', 'P20000741 1    NaN
2007-12-31        A1000     support                 S8MT00010    1.0
2007-12-31        A1500     support                 S6WI00061    2.0
2007-12-31        A1600     support  S4IA00020', 'P20000741 3    NaN

merge=pd.merge(df,d, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
print merge
           catcode_amt type feccandid_amt  amount catcode_disp disposition  \
date                                                                         
1997-12-31       z9600  24K     S6ND00058    2000        A0000     support   

           feccandid_disp  bills  
date                              
1997-12-31      S4HI00011    1.0
```

Or you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print pd.concat([df,d], join='inner', axis=1)

date                                                                         
1997-12-31       z9600  24K     S6ND00058    2000        A0000     support   

           feccandid_disp  bills  
date                              
1997-12-31      S4HI00011    1.0
```

EDIT: [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292959/pandas-merge-data-frames-on-datetime-index#comment60212059_36292959) is right:

I add duplicates to DataFrame `df` (last 2 values in index):

```
print df
           catcode_amt type feccandid_amt  amount
date                                             
1915-12-31       A5000  24K     H6TX08100    1000
1916-12-31       T6100  24K     H8CA52052     500
1954-12-31       H3100  24K     S8AK00090    1000
2007-12-31       J7120  24E     H8OH18088      36
2007-12-31       z9600  24K     S6ND00058    2000

print d
           catcode_disp disposition            feccandid_disp  bills
date                                                                
1997-12-31        A0000     support                 S4HI00011    1.0
2007-12-31        A1000      oppose  S4IA00020', 'P20000741 1    NaN
2007-12-31        A1000     support                 S8MT00010    1.0
2007-12-31        A1500     support                 S6WI00061    2.0
2007-12-31        A1600     support  S4IA00020', 'P20000741 3    NaN

merge=pd.merge(df,d, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

```
print merge
           catcode_amt type feccandid_amt  amount catcode_disp disposition  \
date                                                                         
2007-12-31       J7120  24E     H8OH18088      36        A1000      oppose   
2007-12-31       J7120  24E     H8OH18088      36        A1000     support   
2007-12-31       J7120  24E     H8OH18088      36        A1500     support   
2007-12-31       J7120  24E     H8OH18088      36        A1600     support   
2007-12-31       z9600  24K     S6ND00058    2000        A1000      oppose   
2007-12-31       z9600  24K     S6ND00058    2000        A1000     support   
2007-12-31       z9600  24K     S6ND00058    2000        A1500     support   
2007-12-31       z9600  24K     S6ND00058    2000        A1600     support   

                      feccandid_disp  bills  
date                                         
2007-12-31  S4IA00020', 'P20000741 1    NaN  
2007-12-31                 S8MT00010    1.0  
2007-12-31                 S6WI00061    2.0  
2007-12-31  S4IA00020', 'P20000741 3    NaN  
2007-12-31  S4IA00020', 'P20000741 1    NaN  
2007-12-31                 S8MT00010    1.0  
2007-12-31                 S6WI00061    2.0  
2007-12-31  S4IA00020', 'P20000741 3    NaN
```

Comment: @ jezrael: I just tried the code you recommended: I'm still getting a MemoryError. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What is size of your `RAM` ? What is shape of your DataFrames? `print df.shape` and `print d.shape` ?

Comment: My `df.shape` `(389194, 4)` and my `d.shape is (2910, 4)`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe help function `concat`,  see edit of my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your dates are your indices, in which case you would want to merge on the index, not column. If you have two dataframes, `df_1` and `df_2`:

`df_1.merge(df_2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried it and am still getting a MemoryError. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: try it with two dataframes that are a small subset of your data - say the last 100 rows of each.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problems. You most likely have a lot of `NaT`s.
I removed all my `NaT`s and then performed the join and was able to join it.

```
df = df[df['date'].notnull() == True].set_index('date')
d = d[d['date'].notnull() == True].set_index('date')
df.join(d, how='right')
```