# Time Conversions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

***tldr; How do I convert DateTimeIndex back to a column in a dataframe?***

The long explanation:

I have accelerometer and loadcell data for the same time period, but the timestamps for each device are in different formats and timezones. My current theory is that I need them to be in the same format so that I will be able to merge both datasets into one dataframe.

> My first step was to expedite this process as much as possible by reading in the data correctly. To that end, I combined the date and time data for the Load Data and renamed that column to "Time" so that it would be the same as the Accelerometer data.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

path = r"C:\Users\afhal\Dropbox\Arboriculture\ThesisData\Kane_Shared_Folder\2020Summer"
load_path = path + "\\" + r"ulmus15\Reference\ulmus15loads.csv"
pull_path = path + "\\"+ r"ulmus15\Reference\ulmus15pulls.csv"

df_pull = pd.read_csv(pull_path, skiprows =22, parse_dates = ["Time"])
print(df_pull)
df_load = pd.read_csv(load_path, parse_dates = [["Date","Time"]])
df_load = df_load.rename(columns = {"Date_Time": "Time", "Elapsed mS": "Elapsed S", "Climber": "Load"})
print(df_load)
```

## Results for Accelerometer Data

```
              Time  12159:ch4  12159:ch5  12160:ch4  12160:ch5 <br>
```

0    2020-07-25 13:20:46   52.56000     -27.23      73.34       8.86 
1    2020-07-25 13:20:47   52.18000     -27.04      73.02       8.99 
2    2020-07-25 13:20:48   52.18000     -27.03      73.02       8.98 
3    2020-07-25 13:20:49   52.35000     -27.47      73.04       8.97 
4    2020-07-25 13:20:50   52.31000     -26.84      73.03       8.98 
...                  ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
9266 2020-07-26 11:22:49   81.07000       0.19      80.64      -0.32
9267 2020-07-26 11:22:50   81.75999      -0.08      80.63      -0.32
9268 2020-07-26 11:22:51   81.06000       0.18      80.63      -0.32
9269 2020-07-26 11:22:52   81.77000      -0.08      80.64      -0.31
9270 2020-07-26 11:22:53        NaN        NaN      80.64      -0.31

[9271 rows x 5 columns]

## Results for Load Cell Data

```
    Time  Elapsed S  Load
```

0    2020-07-25 09:26:28       1002     2 
1    2020-07-25 09:26:29       2011     2
2    2020-07-25 09:26:30       3035     3
3    2020-07-25 09:26:31       4037     2
4    2020-07-25 09:26:32       5060     2
...                  ...        ...   ...
1302 2020-07-25 09:48:24    1317109    -2
1303 2020-07-25 09:48:25    1318135    -2
1304 2020-07-25 09:48:26    1319165    -1
1305 2020-07-25 09:48:27    1320177    -2
1306 2020-07-25 09:48:28    1321178    -1

[1307 rows x 3 columns]

> I needed to convert the Accelerometer Data to US/Eastern. My understanding from reading other StackOverflow questions is that I need to change my time column from a pandas DateTime to a pandas DateTimeIndex. I accomplished this with the following code:

```
df_test = df_pull.set_index('Time').index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df_test.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

> And this has put me thoroughly in the weeds.
>
> - Problem 1: I seem to have destroyed my other columns in the process of creating a DateTimeIndex--how do I get them back?
> - Problem 2: A DateTimeIndex is not the same as a DateTime object, and I do not think I can merge them unless I make the DateTimeIndex back into a DateTime object.

Comment: Please revise this to just *one* question.  Someone can surely help you in that case - this is a bit long

Comment: Hope that's a bit better?

Comment: its better.  what output are you expecting exactly?  Can you be more specific about `but I need to correlate the data in one file`?  You can still break this up into separate questions.  One of them sounds like timezone issues, there is another about joining the data

Comment: Thank you for your patience and feedback. Edited again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a great deal of fussing around the Internet, I solved my problem!

```
# CREATE a DateTimeIndex
pull_index = df_pull.set_index('Time').index.astype('datetime64[ns]')

# Localize time with tz
pull_index = pull_index.tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('US/Eastern')

# Back to an naive datetimeindex! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36292959/pandas-merge-data-frames-on-datetime-index
pull_index = pull_index.tz_localize(None)
print(pull_index)

# Create a datetimeindex for the other dataset
load_index = df_load.set_index('Time').index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
print(load_index)

# Add datetimeindex to datasets and delete extra columns
df_pull=df_pull.set_index(pull_index)
df_pull.drop("Time",axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df_pull)

df_load=df_load.set_index(load_index)
df_load.drop("Time",axis=1,inplace=True)
print(df_load)

# Merge by datetimeindex
merge=pd.merge(df_pull,df_load, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```